# Ati X1600 driver problem on Mac

Tags: mac, drivers, macbook

I currently own a 2006 **Macbook Pro** 1.1, and since some months I have recurrent problems of displays bug or artifacts. I searched quickly around to see that a lot of other users on Mac (**iMac or Macbook Pro**) also have the same problem due to a problem for the **X1600** video card. Apparently it's due to overheating problem, in my case even without warming a lot I have very bad display bugs such as **colorful pixel lines**, or **glitches**, and **freeze** and **crash**, all of this on Tiger, Leopard and Snow Leopard.

I found this interesting article [here](http://torley.com/Macbook-Pro-with-ati-radeon-x1600-distorted-video-glitches) talking about this problem and trying to gather people so that **Apple take the serious GPU problem in consideration**.

In one of the comments, an user said he **removed all bundle** named with "radeon" and then he had no more problems under Leopard, and seems ot work fine well too on Snow Leopard. I did the same thing, I removed the bundles of the driver, restart, and no more problems, but not more 3D acceleration, which is not an acceptable solution.

For those interested, here is the list of files to be deleted to stop having this problem.

```
/System/Library/Extensions/ATIRadeonX1000.kext
/System/Library/Extensions/ATIRadeonX1000GA.plugin
/System/Library/Extensions/ATIRadeonX1000GLDriver.bundle
/System/Library/Extensions/ATIRadeonX1000VADriver.bundle
/System/Library/Extensions/ATIRadeonX2000.kext
/System/Library/Extensions/ATIRadeonX2000GA.plugin
/System/Library/Extensions/ATIRadeonX2000GLDriver.bundle
/System/Library/Extensions/ATIRadeonX2000VADriver.bundle
```

I would like to know if there is a way to fix this using other drivers if that's possible or by creating a group to force Apple to make a replacement program in place.

Edit : How to locate those files on your hard drive if you are not under Snow Tiger :

```
sudo find / -iname "*radeon*"
```

Comment: I will recommand you to save the bundle on an external hard drive in order to be able to restore the drivers after. As Mulot said, it is a really extreme solution...

Answer (score 2):

Thanks for the info!
Before going to the last-resort option of entirely disabling the Graphics card, I instead tried to lower the temps that the GPU get to - this has appeared to work very well!

The permanent solution (for me) was using the free & Excellent "Fan Control" SysPref - simply increase the "Base Speed" (for me, from 1500rpm to 2000rpm) and I also reduce the "Upper Threshold" to 70°C - thus the fans will work harder to keep temps down should they rise.
I like this solution because, in theory, it will always makes sure the temp stays below the crash-point (with tweaking of the fan-rpm vs. CPU-Temp settings).  I suppose One can assume that CPU temp and GPU temp are correlated - they are in the same aluminum box!

I coupled that with "iStat Menus" (I think it's ShareWare) to monitor CPU & GPU temp (obviously GPU is more important here).
Dace appears to have the right numbers - as long as my GPU temps is around or below 48°, no line glitches, and no freezes!

Thanks to everyone who posted their thoughts, it was very helpful in tracking down this elusive problem!

Screenshot:
[Fan Control & iStat Menu monitoring](http://www.ocpn.ece.ucsb.edu/index.php/publications/category/51-demis?download=956%3Afan-control-a-istat-menus-cpu-gpu-temp)

Comment: Update:
My computer used to freeze once a day.

This has NOT happened again since I implemented the fixes mentioned above (almost 2 weeks ago)! I am quite happy with the Fan Control SysPref – it is really good.  Ofcourse, faster fans means a slightly louder computer - but at least it is working without having spent a penny!

Answer (score 0):

I too experienced the heat problems with my MacBook pro with the x1600. I am convinced that the graphic issues on my machine are directly related to the temperature of the GPU. Once the temperature gets above 60c my system starts to exhibit graphics glitches (tearing striping etc…).

- I have been using smcfancontrol for years, which does help significantly, but does not help when I get both cores running full blast for more than 5 minutes in a row.
- I have carefully cleaned out the old thermal compound and applied arctic silver, which only reduced the temperatures by about 1-2 degrees celsius. When you do this procedure I made the easily correctable mistake of not tightening the heatsink screws tight enough at first, which amplified the temperature problem

*** – the real solution to this problem for me was to vacuum the rear vent with a powerful (2000W) vacuum cleaner. I spent several minutes pressing the wand of the vacuum tightly against the crack and moving it back and forth where the screen meets the main body of the notebook. I went to the trouble of vacuuming the croissant crumbs out of the keyboard at the same time :) . You will know when you get to the right spots because the smcfancontrol display will show your fans revving up to 7500rpm when the vacuum is over each fan exhaust port. This cleaning procedure shaved at least 15 degrees off of my temperatures.

My computer used to run at 58c at idle, and now it sits at 40c. It used to peak (and often lockup) at 75c, now I am hard pressed to get it above 60c.

Comment: You might want to have the system *off* when you vacuum it, as this is  likely to build up some static electricity...